# How to plot scatter plot for specific rows using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot a scatter plot for specific day .How to plot scatter with only two columns [Saturday and Sunday]?

```
px.scatter(
           df, x="total_bill", y="tip", 
           color="size", facet_col="day"
)


df.day.value_counts()

Sat     87
Sun     76
Thur    62
Fri     19
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

This is scatter plotted for all columns.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to filter your df. It doesn't matter if you do so before or when you call `px`

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()

px.scatter(df[df["day"].isin(["Sat", "Sun"])],
           x="total_bill",
           y="tip", 
           color="size",
           facet_col="day"
)
```